# Access only certain lines of a saved file

Tags: python, numpy

My problem is the following:
I manipulate a shape numpy array (N,) in a notebook jupyter and then save it by doing:

```
f = open('filename')
array.tofile(f)
f.close()
```

which saves my file in binary (filename.dat).

Then, I need to retrieve some elements from array so I load it by doing :

```
array = np.fromfile('filename', dtype=np.float32)
```

but as N is very large, this operation is expensive (in time and memory).

So my question is: how to load only some (consecutive) elements of array, say the slice [a:b]?

Thanks in advance

Sorry if it's obvious but I couldn't find an answer on the web.

Comment: I think you can use memmap to create a memory map of your file and then load the elements you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `offset=a * 4` bytes and `count=b - a` to `np.fromfile` to read the slice `[a:b]` of an array of type float32:

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)

array.tofile("array.bin")

a, b = 10, 20

array2 = np.fromfile("array.bin", offset=a * 4, count=b - a, dtype=np.float32)

print(np.all(array[a:b] == array2))
```

Output:

```
True
```